# Was BaiduTrans the first scalable deployment of Neural Machine Translation?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, history, machine-translation

I read these two [tweets](https://twitter.com/AndrewYNg/status/809790037978062848) written on  2016-12-15 by [Andrew Ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Ng):

> Strong desire for global content made China 1st to develop Neural Machine Translation. US lucky to have so much english content
>
> […]
>
> @ruchitgarg @ylecun Yes, that's what I meant. AFAIK first scalable deployment was BaiduTrans. Earlier rsch by Bengio, many others of course.

Was BaiduTrans the first scalable deployment of Neural Machine Translation?